# windows SYSTEM cmd prompt verification. It is what it says it is?

Tags: windows, cmd, kernel

I have recently downloaded a program that allows the user to purportedly run a windows System cmd prompt. It's not that I don't trust the source, but I would like to test the cmd window to verify it is in fact running as a system user.

I have run the `whoami /user` command and recieved :

```
nt authority\system
```

as the user name. But how do I know that isn't just a manually written command line in order to fool me into believing its legitimacy?

If it were an admin account I would just create a new user or something similar. However I am unfamiliar with the System privileges. Is there a simple command that yields tangible results in order to verify the cmd prompt but doesn't modify my system in any way.

Many thanks.

Comment: Windows 7 and later already has a %SystemRoot%\System32\whoami.exe program. This is often `C:\Windows\System32\whoami.exe`. Are you downloading another whoami program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx), it can display the user and integrity level of a process (You may have to enable those columns).